# Which files are required for a Visual Studio project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'd like to use git to manage my various Visual Studio projects. Unfortunately they seem to consist of a multitude of files beyond the one or two .cs files my code is contained in.

Which of these files is actually required to build the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.csproj, assemblyinfo.cs, plus your code and solution (.sln) file.

Also, you might take a look at [cleansoureplus](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000368.html) from Jeff. This program will clean out all unnecessary files and folders.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's easier to look at a Visual Studio project and know what to exclude from a project.  There are too many different flavors of visual studio projects to possibly list all of the file types which are important.  However the unimportant files usually follow a specific pattern.

In general I exclude the following directories and files

Directories:

- bin
- obj

Files Extensions:

- *.suo
- *.sdf
- *.user
- *.obj
- *.dll
- *.exe

Answer (score 3):

You should only need:

- *.cs code files
- the .csproj file
- any form files (.cs, Designer.cs, and .resx)
- the Properties directory and contents (AssemblyInfo.cs)

Answer (score 1):

All you need are the project and solution files.  csproj, vbproj, sln.

*edit*

I meant in addition to the actual files inside the projects.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to look *in* the project file to see what files are part of it.